# No such instance field: RetrofitClient

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to make an HTTP Client using retrofit 2 and since I'm used to working in Visual Studio I'm having a lot of trouble debugging my code and making it work.

What in the earth is "No such instance field" error?

Very poor help online so far so I have to write out this question.

```
public class ApiUtils {
    private ApiUtils() {}

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://cloudlibraryapiserver.azurewebsites.net/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

This is my ApiUtils class...

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

RetrofitClient class

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("api/books")
    Call<List<Book>> getBooks();

    @POST("api/books")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Book> saveBook(@Field("title") String title,
                        @Field("authorID") int authorID);
}
```

This is my APIService interface (why it doesn't have class implementation? I have no idea since I'm following example from Internet.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private APIService mAPIService;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set View Controls:

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBook);

        // Now do this:
        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

        Call<List<Book>> getBooksCall = mAPIService.getBooks();

        getBooksCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Book>> call, Response<List<Book>> response) {
                List<Book> books = response.body();

                listView.setAdapter(new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this, books));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Book>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "something went wrong - check your internet connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I call **getBooksCall.enqueue** line I get the following error:

> No such instance field: 'mAPIService'

Other posts have accepted answer which said "Android Studio required a restart", I didn't try to restart Android studio but this definitely doesn't seem like right solution.

I need in depth answer, someone with retrofit experience If you answer with how to do it I'm going to need STEP by STEP explanation not just ONE WORD answers like most of these Android questions have,

This is the most frustrating thing ever trying to make this work and NO real answers to be found online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of that apiUtil and in your mainActivity add:

```
Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://cloudlibraryapiserver.azurewebsites.net")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.Create()).build();
```

then you need to get your service:

```
APIService service = retrofit.Create(APIService.class);
```

then call the book list:

```
 Call<List<Book>> getBooksCall = service.getBooks();
```

///callback ect..

The reason why it wasnt getting any service is because you missed the first step. hope that helps.

Comment: I forgot to add the code for RetrofitClient class... which does basically same thing that you wrote

Comment: I'm getting null reference exception, I guess retrofit isn't built the way it's supposed to... I don't have time to investigate this now but I will post update

Comment: for some weird reason I'm not getting null reference exception anymore, even though didn't change the code at all